# django context request error when USE_I18N is True

Tags: django, django-middleware

I use website with 2 languages, and i get this error:

```
2014-12-07 03:05:51: (mod_fastcgi.c.2695) FastCGI-stderr:   File "/home/ikresoft/oglasise/web/templatetags/web_tags.py", line 157, in main_menu
2014-12-07 03:05:51: (mod_fastcgi.c.2695) FastCGI-stderr:     request = context['request']
2014-12-07 03:05:51: (mod_fastcgi.c.2695) FastCGI-stderr:   File "/home/ikresoft/virtualenv/oglasise/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/context.py", line 56, in __getitem__
2014-12-07 03:05:51: (mod_fastcgi.c.2695) FastCGI-stderr:     raise KeyError(key)
```

when `USE_I18N` is `False` i don't get this error..

And when have 2 languages, when access to website with sufix `/en/` it works, but without that sufix in deployment mode i get that error..

On `DEBUG = True` everything works..

web_tags.py:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('web/main_menu.html', takes_context=True)
def main_menu(context, active_menu):
    from postman.models import Message

    request = context['request']
    try:
        unread_count = Message.objects.inbox_unread_count(request.user)
    except:
        unread_count = False
    return {
        'request': request,
        'unread_count': unread_count,
        'active_menu': active_menu
    }
```

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
    # 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'fandjango.middleware.FacebookMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'pipeline.middleware.MinifyHTMLMiddleware',
    'mobi.middleware.MobileDetectionMiddleware',
)
```

On development server in terminal i get message:

```
Not Found: /
```

but it redirects to `/en/`..
On deployment server that isn't working